# How to find the percentage of values present in one from another table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

table 1:

```
id name
1 abc
2 xyz
3 pqr
```

table 2:

```
ids loc
1  loc1
2  loc2
3  loc3
4  loc4
5  loc5
```

desired o/p:

table3:

```
match total percent
3      5     60
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS reach, COUNT(DISTINCT ids) AS total
FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.ids
```

And this is giving me this which is not correct:

```
match total percent
 3    3     100
```

Can someone help me in getting this correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: So you want a solution in MySQL's SQL dialect, T-SQL, pl-sql *and* Bigquery? No. Pick one; don't tag spam. Posting multiple languages and asking for a solution doesn't help us help you as we don't know what language you *really* need. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using an **only** that RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af97a/24)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID int,Name varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE Table2 (ID int, Name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO `Table1` (ID,Name) VALUES (1,'abc'),(2,'xyz'),(3,'lmm'),(4,'pqr'),(5,'cde');
INSERT INTO `Table2`(ID,Name) VALUES (1,'abc'),(2,'xyz'),(3,'pqr');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.id) AS Matching, 
count(t1.ID) AS TheTotal
, (COUNT(t2.id)/count(t1.ID) *100) AS Percentage
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af97a/24/0)**:

```
| Matching | TheTotal | Percentage |
|----------|----------|------------|
|        3 |        5 |         60 |
```